# Running Apache Drill on OpenShift fails at startup

Tags: openshift, apache-drill

does anyway have experience on running apache drill on openshift?

I'm having a problem where I'm trying to run the standard docker-image in openshift
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/drill
really just the embedded mode without trying to configure anything.

it works fine if I run it in my local docker desktop daemon and it's totally fine.
but when I deploy it to openshift it becomes totally weird by not even starting up.

my deployment yaml is very straight forward:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-drill
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: apache-drill-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: apache-drill-svc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: apache-drill
          image: apache/drill
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
            limits:
              cpu: 4
              memory: 4Gi
```

But once it launches this is the feedback that it fails to start because of the log directories:
[image: pod events]
[image: pod log]

I believe it might be because of this guidelines regarding the security.
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines

so because of that I've tried to create my own image wrapping the official one:
https://hub.docker.com/r/cstmgl/adrill/tags (probably there are better ways to do this)
anyway I still get an error even thought the image also works final in my local docker daemon but if I try it on OpenShift I get this error:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-drill
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: apache-drill-svc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: apache-drill-svc
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: apache-drill
          image: cstmgl/adrill:1.18.0
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 1
              memory: 1Gi
            limits:
              cpu: 4
              memory: 4Gi
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'll update this soon with the actual startup error it's rather basic but I believe it's a problem with the user running the application just not sure how to get around it.

[image: second event logs]

```
ERROR: Drill config file not readable: /opt/drill/conf/drill-override.conf - Wrong user?
```

Anyway I changed that image also to something like this in my dockerfile

```
FROM cstmgl/adrill:1.18.0

ARG APP_ROOT=/opt/drill

RUN chmod -R ugo+rw ${APP_ROOT}

RUN echo ${UID}

USER ${UID}

WORKDIR ${DRILL_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT [ "drill-embedded" ]
```

but still not working, this is the log:

```
Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failed to login. (state=,code=0)
java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failed to login.
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.exec.exception.DrillbitStartupException: Failed to login.
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.login(BootStrapContext.java:161)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.<init>(BootStrapContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:171)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:135)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:133)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.KerberosAuthException: failure to login: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
    at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:660)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.login(BootStrapContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.<init>(BootStrapContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:171)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:135)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1847)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:660)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.login(BootStrapContext.java:156)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.lang.NullPointerException: invalid null input: name
    at com.sun.security.auth.UnixPrincipal.<init>(UnixPrincipal.java:71)
    at com.sun.security.auth.module.UnixLoginModule.login(UnixLoginModule.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:755)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.createLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:710)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:660)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.login(BootStrapContext.java:156)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.BootStrapContext.<init>(BootStrapContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:171)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.<init>(Drillbit.java:135)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.<init>(DrillConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:67)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.calcite.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:138)
    at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:75)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:135)
    at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:192)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1364)
    at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1244)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:38)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:730)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:410)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:515)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:267)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:206)

    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:856)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:195)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:682)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:680)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation$HadoopLoginContext.login(UserGroupInformation.java:1926)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doSubjectLogin(UserGroupInformation.java:1837)
... 25 more
Apache Drill 1.18.0
"Two things are infinite: the universe and Drill; and I'm not sure about the universe."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come across this problem myself and after some hard googling, reading this post a few times, and some OpenShift documentation I stumbled upon the way to resolve this.

The problem you are seeing in the logs indicates there is a problem with the name, if you look into sqlline.log you will see that user.name and user.home are empty - it looks something like this:

```
INFO o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Drillbit environment: user.name=?
INFO o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Drillbit environment: user.home=?
```

It seems not everyone knows this but basically OpenShift generates user IDs upon pod creation and the user does not have a home or a name, but in an older version of documentation from OpenShift they provide a way to generate 'default' for the username:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.10/creating_images/guidelines.html#openshift-specific-guidelines

Specifically you want this uid_entrypoint script in your image that you can run to generate default for your 100xxxxx user:
https://github.com/RHsyseng/container-rhel-examples/blob/master/starter-arbitrary-uid/bin/uid_entrypoint

**You will need to make sure that when building your image that you change the permission of /etc/passswd in order to be able to modify it when you start your image**

After I did this I was able to start Drill and you should see the user.name and user.home updated in the log file sqlline.log:

```
INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Drillbit environment: user.name=default
INFO  o.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit - Drillbit environment: user.home=/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application needs root access try this

Either you can add `User root` in dockerfile just after FROM statement.

or

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n <yournamespace>
```

Comment: I'll try to do that but I believe my company explicitly forbids apps from running with root user. that's why I'm trying to force the user id somehow there

Comment: or you can chnage user by using ```Ùser 1001``` just before the entrypoint. so you will start app with root and then you can change to normal user

Comment: I really can't do that, my company security policy actually intentionally prevents that. the application should not require root to run

Comment: @MiguelCosta have you tried adding ```privileged``` flag to deployment

Comment: like i mentioned I cannot do that, it's not allowed in my cluster.
$ oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default -n drill-test
Error from server (Forbidden): securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io "anyuid" is forbidden: User "U001120" cannot get securitycontextconstraints.security.openshift.io at the cluster scope: no RBAC policy matched
I believe my user is not allowed to do this, but anyway this is not the goal to actually escalate the privileges of the namespace so this can run. I'm trying this 
https://www.openshift.com/blog/a-guide-to-openshift-and-uids